# Elasticsearch Highlights document randomly

Tags: elasticsearch, search

When i run a search

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query":"Rose wa",
              "fuzziness": "AUTO"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "name": {}
    }
  }
}
```

then following documents come in matches

```
        "_index" : "product",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "52486",
        "_score" : 19.770897,
        "_source" : {",
          "category_code" : "personalcare",
          "name" : "Nivea Rosewater Face Wash (100 Ml)",
          "category_name" : "Personal Care  "
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "product",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "120830",
        "_score" : 17.775726,
        "_source" : {
          "category_code" : "beverages",
          "name" : "3 Roses 500G",
          "category_name" : "Beverages"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "name" : [
            "3 <em>Roses</em> 500G"
          ]
        }
      },
```

**why some document have highlighted fields while other don't?**

and how do i ensure that highlight is always present for matched documents